# Upload a photo to a friend's wall

Tags: javascript, facebook

The Facebook site itself has the option to go to a friend's profile and upload a photo from your computer. Is there any way to do this through the Javascript API? Or are there security/privacy issues that prevent it?

After hours of searching I haven't been able to find a clear answer to my question, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd need to use the same Graph API call you'd use to publish a message to a friend's feed but along with the message you'd define a `picture` attribute:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

In the link above, scroll down to the `Publishing` section and see the arguments for the first method in the table. The `PROFILE_ID` would be your friend's profile. You'd use that call with the `FB.api` function in the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and if I make a call to /me/photos the picture is uploaded without issues. As far as I can see I don't have access to /FRIEND_ID/photos, which would make sense, but then I tried /FRIEND_ID/feed and the message is posted, but with no image attached.